# React update state maintaining previous states with fixed sorting

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-hooks

I need to update an state of objects using prevState from useState().

I have this callback that updates the data state maintaining all previous addresses:

```
onSuccess: (address) =>
   setData((prevState) => {
      return [...prevState, address];
   }),
```

But it is sorting each time I call this callback, for ex:

The first time this callback is called, the previous state is [], the second time is

```
[
  {address: 'England London Islington', miles: '15.81', kilometers: '25.45'}
]
```

The third time it continues the right way, with Islington at index 1 and Lambeth at index 0:

```
[
    {
        "address": "England London Lambeth",
        "miles": "14.29",
        "kilometers": "22.99"
    },
    {
        "address": "England London Islington",
        "miles": "15.81",
        "kilometers": "25.45"
    }
]
```

But after that the prevState sorts in a different way the elements:

```
[
    {
        "address": "England London Westminster",
        "miles": "13.83",
        "kilometers": "22.25"
    },
    {
        "address": "England London Islington",
        "miles": "15.81",
        "kilometers": "25.45"
    },
    {
        "address": "England London Lambeth",
        "miles": "14.29",
        "kilometers": "22.99"
    }
]
```

As you can see, Islington is at the middle of Lambeth and Westminster, and I don't it that way, I need to keep the sorting so I can use in a list, but I have no idea how to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .sort() build in function to sort the array as you like:

```
 const months = ['March', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec'];
months.sort();
console.log(months);
// expected output: Array ["Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "March"]
```

Reference: MDN Array.prototype.sort()

Comment: But in my case I would sort by which term? I need to keep the addresses as I added them to the array

Answer (score 0):

Object de-structuring and re-assigning will lead to unexpected results and data transitions. I would recommend to avoid that approach as a whole

One potential way to go about this would be to the data value itself in the udpateData hook

so for example:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{val: 1}, {val: 2}])
...
...
onSuccess: (address) => {
    setData(data.push(address)) // Assuming address is an object of same type as data array
}
```

Doing it this way would also ensure that information is stored as it was entered, hence avoiding the need for sorting

Comment: Tried it but typescript gave me this error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IData[] | undefined>'

IData is the object above containing address, miles and kilometers

Comment: Could you show on how the data, setData hook is defined?